# Using previous running activity instead of starting a new one

Tags: android, android-activity

it is possible to Use previous running activity instead of starting a new one without affecting the back stack?

for example activity A -> B -> C -> A
i want to achieve that the system will use Activity A instanse without starting a new one, and without affecting the back stack.

so when user will click Back he will travel the original path and the last activity will be A not B, by using simply singleTop/ReorderToFront flag i will be able to use the original activity but i will lose the back stack

i will like to achive a "browser like experience" so every time the user will click back he will back to his previous page the case can be much more complex then that for example

A -> B -> C -> A -> B ->B -> C -> D -> A etc...

Comment: In this case, you must Make your Activities as `static`

Comment: it is a bad idea to keep activties in a static way

Comment: Yeah, It's bad for performance. But, if it's not static and you want to achieve your goal then it will effect the Stack.

Comment: also i will not able to use the natural android stack i will have to manange the back stack on my own.

Comment: Yeah True.. I would recommend to use static, or may be someone will give you another idea.

Comment: please refer https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242

Comment: there is nothing pointing to my case any change of lunching mode is also affecting the back stack

Comment: Maybe consider using Fragments?

Comment: I am searching for a solution based on activities

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emulate the behaviour of a browser, then you should just allow Android to create new instances of the activities, which it will do. The user can then press BACK to navigate back through the list of activities.

You can't reuse existing instances and rearrange them and still maintain the backstack, because when Android moves an Activity from wherever it is in the stack to the front (which you can do using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`) it removes it from where it was in the back stack.

If you really want to reuse existing instances and maintain the back stack then you will have to implement this yourself:

Create a variable `static ArrayList<Class> stack` that you use as a stack to remember which `Activity` was used at what point in the navigation. Everytime you launch an `Activity` you should us `startActivity()` and make sure that you set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` so that an existing instance will be moved to the front. When you call `startActivity`()`you must also push the`Class`instance of the`Activity` onto your stack. This allows you to keep track of which activities where launched in what order. This works all fine going forwards. Now the tricky part comes when the user presses BACK.

Override `onBackPressed()` in each `Activity`. When `onBackPressed()` is called, do this:

```
// pop my Activity off the stack
Class myClass = stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
// Check if there are any more instances of my Activity in the stack
//  Don't finish this instance if the instance exists in the stack
if (!stack.contains(myClass)) {
    // There are no more instances of my Activity in the stack, so
    //   finish this instance
    finish();
    // Check if this is the root Activity, if so we are done!
    if (stack.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
}
// Get the Class representing the previous Activity from the top of the stack
Class activityClass = stack.get(stack.size() - 1);
// Launch that Activity
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

This will pop the current `Activity` off the stack, finish the `Activity` if there are no more instances of it in the stack, get the previous `Activity` from the top of the stack and launch it bringing it to the front. This gives the illusion you are looking for.