# Android: Activities Navigation loop - preserve memory stack

Tags: android

I'm working on a social android application with a navigation loop beaviour like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> B -> C -> B -> ...
```

Where the activity `B` is a list of followers while the activity `C` is the profile of user clicked in the activity B.

When I start the navigation loop between B and C, I notice that the memory of the device grows up exponentially. The goal is to create this loop preserving the history back stack and using the same `B activity object` in memory.

1. How can I do this?
2. Do I need to create a custom back stack management object by hard-coding?
3. I tried using android:launchMode="SingleTask" on activity B but the behavior kill the back stack history

Comment: I've closed this a duplicate. The linked question is basically the same and I've also answered it with a similar answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simulate this behaviour by reusing the existing instance of each `Activity` and keeping track of which activities are launched in your own stack so that you can process the BACK key properly.

Have a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430070/769265). It describes more or less how to do this.